# clear back stack except last two activities

Tags: android, android-activity, back-stack

For Activity A, B, C and D I have a flow like A->B->C->D. When I'm going to start D from C I need to clear A and B from back stack.

Comment: Take a look at this page : https://inthecheesefactory.com/blog/understand-android-activity-launchmode/en

Comment: why you have A and B in the backstack if you're going to start from D / C ?

Comment: @WADVL if back is pressed from C I'll need B and A, but when I'll reach D I don't need A and B but still I'll need C if back is pressed from D